# CSS - Is it possible to add a border on the box shadow?

Tags: html, css, sass, box-shadow

Is it possible to add a border to a `box-shadow`?

I want to create a class with a coloured offset with that offset being outlined in a black border.

Now I know I can create a div and offset it to get this desired look, but I want to know if it's possible to do it without so I can just create a class and add it to the divs that I want to do this too.

I attached a snippet showing the colour offset but I would like the red offset to be outlined in a black border.

```css
.example-div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add additional box-shadows to your div to get that effect. For your case update your box-shadow property to something like this

```
box-shadow: -5px 5px red, 
    -5px 5px 0px 3px black;
```

This resource has tons of more info about box-shadows and it's syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow if you want to follow.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a CSS pseudo-element to your class which automatically will add another object behind the main object on each element which has that class. Use absolute position, a negative `z-index`, 100% `width` and `height` and determine the offset with the `left` or `right` and `bottom` or `top` parameters as in this example:

(note: You need a non-transparent background for the main element when you use this method)

```css
.example-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.example-div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) and [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) aren't going to be much help unfortunately, as the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) doesn't really *exist* and those will still target the element's bounding box (which is unaffected by the box-shadow).

You could make use of [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) or [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), but that gets a little complicated for what you're trying to do.

One thing you could do is make use of **multiple box-shadows**. `box-shadow` takes a comma separated list of shadows, and it's supported in all majors browsers. The trick here would be to make use of the 4th (underutilized IMHO) parameter for box-shadow, called `spread-radius`. This will "spread" (expand) or "choke" (shrink) the box shadow's reference frame by that many pixels *before* the blur radius is applied.

In your case, for a 2px wide "border" around the box-shadow, you could do the following:

```css
.example-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px red, -5px 5px 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-div"></div>
```